# django cms plugin - editing related object automatically publish changes

Tags: python, django, django-cms

On editing related object used via `TabularInline` changes for that automatically publish on page. While editing related object request goes through admin page.

On live editing page, when changed is made in cms plugin for related object, request goes through admin page. Than changes for that related objects are automatically published on page without need to use button for publish changes on site. Also same situation happens when related object is saved via admin page.

models:

```
from cms.models.pluginmodel import CMSPlugin
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as __
from djangocms_text_ckeditor.fields import HTMLField
from filer.fields.image import FilerImageField


from plugins.generic.cards.styles import (
    CARD_OPTIONS,
    HOVER,
    MARGIN_SIZES,
    CARD_SECTION_OPTIONS,
    HEADER_SECTION_OPTIONS
)
from plugins.generic.global_choices import (
    BUTTON_COLOR, LINK_TARGET, BACKGROUND_COLOR, BORDER_COLOR, LINK_COLOR,
)

from .utils import ChoiceArrayField, GridSystem


class Card(models.Model):
    """Generic card model that is compatible with the Bootstrap grid system."""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    size = models.ForeignKey(
        GridSystem,
        verbose_name=__('Card size'),
        help_text=__(
            'Specify card size for different resolutions using '
            'grid system from Bootstrap.'
        ),
    )
    background = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=__('Card background color'),
        max_length=100,
        choices=BACKGROUND_COLOR,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        help_text=__('Transparent by default.'),
    )
    hover = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=__('Card hover effect'),
        max_length=100,
        choices=HOVER,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        help_text=__(
            'Choose what should happen when card is pointed with a cursor.'
        ),
    )
    options = ChoiceArrayField(
        models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=CARD_OPTIONS),
        verbose_name=__('More options'),
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        help_text=__(
            'Hold down "Control", or "Command" on a Mac, '
            'to select more than one.'
        ),
    )

    hubspot_portal_id = models.CharField(
        max_length=128,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        help_text=__('Portal ID of form created in HubSpot.'),
    )

    hubspot_form_id = models.CharField(
        max_length=128,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        help_text=__('Form ID of form created in HubSpot.'),
    )

    icon = FilerImageField(blank=True, null=True)
    icon_link = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=__('Icon Link'),
        max_length=255,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        help_text=__(
            'Slug of current page subpage or full url. '
            'You can use "#" as a placeholder.'
        ),
    )
    title = HTMLField(blank=True, null=True)
    description = HTMLField(blank=True, null=True)
    link = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=__('Link'),
        max_length=255,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        help_text=__(
            'Slug of current page subpage or full url. '
            'You can use "#" as a placeholder.'
            'If "Whole card is redirecting" is enabled whole card pointing'
            'to this link.'
        ),
    )
    link_text = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        default=__('Learn more'),
        help_text=__(
            'Will not appear if link was not provided.'
        ),
    )
    link_color = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        choices=LINK_COLOR,
        help_text=__('Type in color of link text.'),
    )
    button_color = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=__('Button type.'),
        max_length=100,
        choices=BUTTON_COLOR,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        help_text=__(
            'Transform link to look like button.'
        ),
    )
    button_target = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        verbose_name=__('Button target.'),
        choices=LINK_TARGET,
        default='_self',
        help_text=__('Select target of link / button.'),
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = __('Card')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def columns(self):
        return self.size.bootstrap()

    @property
    def effects(self):
        """Returns formatted CSS class names ready to place in html."""
        options = self.options or []
        return ' '.join(options + list(
            filter(None, [self.background, self.hover])
        ))


class CardsModel(CMSPlugin):
    """Model for CardsPlugin."""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    title = HTMLField(blank=True, null=True)
    description = HTMLField(blank=True, null=True)
    background = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=__('Section background color'),
        max_length=100,
        choices=BACKGROUND_COLOR,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    border = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=__('Section border color'),
        max_length=100,
        choices=BORDER_COLOR,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    header_options = ChoiceArrayField(
        models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=HEADER_SECTION_OPTIONS),
        verbose_name=__('Header section options'),
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        help_text=__(
            'Hold down "Control", or "Command" on a Mac, '
            'to select more than one.'
        ),
    )
    cards_options = ChoiceArrayField(
        models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=CARD_SECTION_OPTIONS),
        verbose_name=__('Card section options'),
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        help_text=__(
            'Hold down "Control", or "Command" on a Mac, '
            'to select more than one.'
        ),
    )
    margin_top = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=__('Custom margin on top of container.'),
        choices=MARGIN_SIZES,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        max_length=100,
    )

    cards = models.ManyToManyField(
        Card, related_name='card_section', through='CardCardsModel'
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def copy_relations(self, old_instance):
        """Copy objects from many-to-many relation during publishing."""
        for card in old_instance.cards.order_by('cardcardsmodel__id'):
            CardCardsModel.objects.create(
                card=card, card_section=self,
            )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = __('CardsContainer')


class CardCardsModel(models.Model):
    """Model handling many-to-many relation of CardsModel with Card."""
    card = models.ForeignKey(Card)
    card_section = models.ForeignKey(CardsModel)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = __('Card')
        verbose_name_plural = __('Add or edit cards')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.card.name
```

plugin:

```
from cms.plugin_base import CMSPluginBase
from cms.plugin_pool import plugin_pool
from django.contrib import admin
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as __

from .models.cards import Card, CardsModel


class CardsAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Card.card_section.through
    extra = 0


class CardsPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
    model = CardsModel
    name = __('Cards')
    inlines = (CardsAdmin, )
    render_template = 'cards.html'
    exclude = ('cards', )

    def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
        context = super().render(context, instance, placeholder)
        context['section'] = instance
        context['cards'] = instance.cards.order_by('cardcardsmodel__id')
        return context


plugin_pool.register_plugin(CardsPlugin)
```